# File Recovery and System Repair

Tags: files, data-recovery, system, boot-repair, restore

My staging server, an Ubuntu 13.04, crashed and I need to recover some web files. I tried doing the `boot-repair` for 5 times now, but every time I run the `boot-repair`, the *Recommended Repair* option is not showing. My only option was *Create Boot summary* and my last `boot-repair` report is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/7216185/.

I am using an Acer Aspire 3610.

Comment: Why not use LiveCD for files recovery?

Comment: I apologized for the incomplete information - I actually am getting  Unknown file system - Grub rescue> so i tried to use LiveCD and install boot-repair from the "Try Ubuntu" environment, and that is where the "Recommended Repair" is not showing up

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

Boot repair wouldn't recover  files from a crashed pc or deleted partitions. It simply repair the boot-files or it would reinstall the grub on your disk and then update it.

From the [boot-repair log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7216185/), it was clearly shown that there is no Ubuntu partition other than the swap partition.There may be a chance of getting your Ubuntu partition deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer avinash. I actually run boot-repair in the hope of getting my grub running. Apparently, that was not the issue, so I run fsck on dev/sda1 and got a lot of errors. I am rebooting now but I am getting error sbin/init no such file, ...not syncing, would there be a chance of getting the files?

Comment: It's not possible to get your Ubuntu working.You can recover some of the files but not all.It's better to reinstall Ubuntu after removing the badblocks on that disk.

Comment: This would be my first time to re-install Ubuntu. How can I recover some files? Can I do that if I re-install Ubuntu on the same system? I don't want to take any chances of installing Ubuntu on the same system if there is a way to recover files before doing so. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Try testdisk to recover files from that partition.